# The restriction of the quotient map $X-A \to X/A-A/A$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let  $A$ be a closed subspace. I need to prove that the restriction of the quotient map $X-A \to X/A - A/A$ is a homeomorphism.
I can see this map is continuous and surjective because the quotient map $X \to X/A$ is. Also, it's injective because we're taking $A$ out of $X$. I just don't know how to prove that it has a continuos inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the restriction $q’$ of the standard quotient map $q$ to the domain $X-A$ is open, as we already know it is a continuous bijection. So let $U$ be open in $X-A$ and note that this means that this $U$ is also open in $X$, as $A$ is closed in $X$. And by the definition of the quotient map ( we’re outside $A$), $q^{-1}[q'[U]]=U$ and this implies, by the definition of the quotient topology that $q'[U]$ is open in $X{/}A$ and so in the codomain as well.

Comment: I still don't understand something. If $U  \subset X-A$ is open in $X-A$, that means $U \cap (X-A)$ is open in $X$, but $U \cap (X-A)=U$ since $U \subset X-A$, so $U$ is open in $X$. I don't see where I used that $A$ is closed.

Comment: @Twink $U \subseteq X-A$ open means $U= V \cap (X-A)$ for some open subset $V$ of $X$ (subspace topology definition) but as $X-A$ is also open (!), this writes $U$ as the intersection of two open subsets of $X$, so itself open already.

Comment: Oh, right. And $q^{-1}[q'[U]]=U$ by the defintion of the quotient map? Or just because $q$ is bijective and $q=q'$ in $U$?

Comment: @Twink both, really.

Answer (score 0):

The final topology is local in the base, i.e. if $f: Y \to Z$ is a continuous map, and $Z$ has the final topology, then any open subspace $U \subset Z$ also has the final topology of the map $f^{-1}(U) \to U$.

Applied to your problem this means that $X \setminus A \to  (X / A) \setminus (A / A)$ is a quotient of topological spaces. But a bijective quotient is a homeomorphism, because it exactly identifies open sets.

Comment: What role plays $A$ being closed?

Comment: @Twink Closedness gives that $X \setminus A$ is open, and hence $(X/A) \setminus (A/A)$ is open as well.